# C# getting file path of an Image in an imagebox

Tags: c#

I have a database with a table "product" in it and in this table there as a field called "PackingPicture" od type Image. I have a form in which I load a record details including the image.
Is there a way to also load  the image file path to a textbox? 
The reason I want to do this is to that I want to be able to updte the record using sql update query in this form. I wnat to user to be able to update any data filed in this form whether it's the image or not. Is there a way to get the file path upon retrieving the image from the database?
alternatively, if there is a way to save the picture itself without the file path I would be pleased to know.

My code for retrieving data:

```
public void getData(string brand, string product)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Connection c = new Connection();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productNumber = @Product and brandNumber=@brand", c.con);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    c.con.Open();
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", brand);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", product);
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        comboBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); 
        //Where ColumnName is the Field from the DB that you want to display
        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();             
    }

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        byte[] img = (byte[])(dr["PackingPicture"]);              
        if (img == null)
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        else
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(img);
            pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);  
        }
    }

    c.con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the image field is a BLOB in the DB, so what do you mean by "file path"?

Comment: You store the image in the database, which column did you store the original file path in?

Comment: I didn't, I wanted to know if there is any other way to do that, form your comments I see there is no way so upon loading the image to the picture box how d I save it to using a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the file path upon retrieving the image from the
>   database?

If you haven't saved the file path, you cannot retrieve what is not present.

> Alternatively, if there is a way to save the picture itself without
>   the file path

after assigning to the picturebox, you can save the picture from picture box like

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save("yourfilepath", yourformat);
```

or you can save it through the stream

```
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(img))
{
   FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("yourfile");
   fs.Write(stream.ToArray());
   fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: How do I save it through the stream?

Comment: What excatly should I put in "yourfile", and what is "ms"?

Comment: ms is your memory stream, and yourfile is the name of file to which you intend to write to

Answer (score 1):

There is no file path because the image exists in memory and in the database, but not in any particular image file. Therefore you need to save it, which you can do like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save("c:\\path\\to\\image.gif", ImageFormat.Gif); // you have to know your image format
```